# Given the predicate Q(x,y):xy =1 where x ∈ Z and y ∈ Z..Determine the true values of the following statements. Explain each of your answer

Tags: predicate-logic

Given the predicate
Q(x,y):xy = 1 where x ∈ Z and y ∈ Z.
Determine the true values of the following statements. Explain each of  your answer
**1)∃x Q(1,y)
2)∀x∃y Q(x,y)
3)∃x∀y Q(x,y)**

My self-do answer is
**1)Yes. For some x as 1, there is a y for x so xy = 1.
2)False. Not for every x there is a y from Z so xy = 1. Counter example: x =2.
3)False. There is not every y for some x so xy = 1. Counter example: x = 2.**

Is my understanding and proof correct?

Comment: 1) is a predicate, not a statement. -- 3) You cannot disprove $\exists x\ldots$ with a counter-example / specific $x$

Comment: But the question asked me to determine the true values of the statements, so if it is not a statement then how should I get the answer?
For question 3, so I cannot use x as counter example but I can use y instead? like y = 3.

Comment: @HanyiKoh $\exists x~Q(1,y)$ is a predicate because $y$ occurs free. Check for typos.